# Any ways to get older Razer Blade BIOS versions?

Tags: laptop, bios, laptop-repair, version, blade

I'm having problems with USB connections with my Razer Blade 15 2019 Advanced. I've tried fully resetting and reinstalling Windows 10 to no avail.

I'm really thinking it's the BIOS that has a problem, since I remember updating it a few days before I first had problems.

Even if this is likely to not solve USB port problems, I would still appreciate if anyone shows a way to install older BIOS versions since I'm really desperate to fix this.

Comment: Have a look at http://drivers.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=350&nav=0

Comment: They only have the latest drivers in that site

Comment: I see there drivers dating from 10 years ago,

Comment: Those are the years that the laptop models were created, not the years of when the driver was created. My laptop model is the Razer Blade 15" (2019) Advanced - if you click on this within that webpage, then click Hardware Drivers, you'll see that all the drivers there are just the latest ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Razer Blade 15 2019 Advanced is
[version 1.04](http://rzr.to/wpnaI).

The previous version 1.03 is [still available](http://rzr.to/CaOyK).

Comment: Thank you so much, but it said "This firmware tool is for use only with Blade and compatible system". If this were the right link for my laptop model, I'm guessing Razer doesn't allow downgrading BIOS to older versions :(

Comment: Yes, it seems that Razer does not allow this. You have here the right answer, but trying to do more than the above may result in a bricked device. Not recommended.

Comment: Would you please send me the webpage wherein you got these links? I need to verify that these are indeed the correct versions for my laptop.

I might've found a workaround so I need to take safety measures to prevent bricking my system.

Comment: I found in the [Razer Blade 15 (Mid 2019) Advanced - BIOS Updater Guide](https://dl.razerzone.com/drivers/Razer%20Blade%2015%22%20Mid%202019/Razer%20Blade%2015%20%28Mid%202019%29%20Advanced%20-%20BIOS%20Updater%20Guide.pdf) and in the [Razer Blade 15" (Mid 2019) Base Model - BIOS Updater v1.03 Guide](http://drivers.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=3336&nav=0,350,888,900).